# Disable class method at compile time if template value is castable to a bool

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want to disable the no-arg method on this class if the type `T` that is contained in the class can be casted to a bool.

I've been trying out some SFINAE stuff with `enable_if`, however I've been run into a lot of problems doing that. Is what I want possible?

```
template <typename T>
struct Watch {
    T t;

    // Enable if and only if bool(t) can be performed
    void stop() {
        // ...
    }

    void stop(int secondsFromNow) {
        // ...
    }
};

int main() {
    Watch<int> watch;
    watch.stop();
    watch.stop(5);

    Watch<string> watchStr;
    //watchStr.stop();
    watchStr.stop(2);
}
```

After reading through many stack overflow posts about hiding things with SFINAE and templates, I've been unable to make other things work for me.

How can I make calling `stop()` on a `Watch` with an element that is not castable to a boolean fail at compile time if someone tries to call it, without affecting any other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct idiom in such cases---when you want to remove the function from overload resolution based on the template arguments to the *class*, and not the arguments to the function itself---is to defer the instantiation of the signature until the point at which the function is called by using default arguments:

```
template <typename U = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U, bool>>>
void stop();
```

Here, the attempt to compute the `enable_if` type will not occur until `stop` is called and `U` is given a value, so SFINAE kicks in.

In some cases, you might simply want the function to not get declared at all when the compile-time condition is not met. You can accomplish this by inheriting from a CRTP base class that either does or does not contain the function in question.